# Data available through the Consumer API

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I was trying to see if the API has the ability to update something on the account, mainly the E-Statements value to see if they have E-Statements enabled. I was looking through the claims and couldn't find a claim in particular that would give me this info.

I then went on to check the Consumer API and could not find an endpoint that can possibly give me this info. Is that data unavailable through the Consumer API? I would like to read and update that field.

Is there a list of Core fields that Banno makes available to us? Or would looking through the API Reference be enough to see all of the values Banno makes available to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Statements" fall under the category of [Documents](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/documents/) in the Consumer API.

- (Admittedly this is not *obvious*, so we've taken a note to add some clarity around "statements" being a subset of "documents").

You'll want to read the sections on determining "Eligibility" and also how to "Determine whether a user is enrolled".

- The combination of *both* is necessary, i.e. there isn't a single 'value' or 'attribute' that answers the question.